# Why Nginx rejects cURL requests

Tags: curl, nginx

When I access this URL for example:

> http://ethiopia.yellowpg.com/listings/et5000-fish-production-marketing-enterprise

from any browsers it works. but if I try it with curl doing the following

> curl http://ethiopia.yellowpg.com/listings/et5000-fish-production-marketing-enterprise

I get the following error.

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.3</center>
</body>
</html>
```

How is Nginx detecting this is a cURL request? And is there any way to get around this problem?

Comment: maybe need some http-headers

Comment: @Deadooshka Do you have any idea how to ?

Comment: maybe it needs an user-agent header. `curl -H "User-Agent: Firefox/29.0" -H "Accept: */*" URL`

Comment: @Deadooshka Amazing. It worked. Can you answer it pls, so I can mark it as answered. Plus, I have one more question. Can I also send a different IP? as REMOTE_ADDR: fake.ip.addre.ss ?

Comment: you can specify any proxy. The parameter depends on its protocol. http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Comment: Oh. I think this would not work. Because, if I was to set a fake IP. Then cURL would send the response to that IP. Which means I won't get any result back. Thanks for the answer